# disable/enable select depending on value vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have 2 select fields:

first field:

```
ns-dropdown-item(item-id="6")    
  ns-select(:placeholder="$t('users.role')", v-model="newLeader.role",
    :options="roleOptions", @change="activeIfCoororMan")
```

second field is disable

```
ns-dropdown-item(item-id="7")    
  ns-select(:placeholder="$t('users.client')", v-model="client", 
    :options="clients", :disabled="true")
```

this is my vue data:

```
export default {
  template: template(),
  data() {
    return {
      newLeader: null,
      client: null,
      clients: [],
      errors: {},
      roleOptions: [
        {value: 'coordinator', label: this.$t('users.roleOptions.coordinator')},
        {value: 'manager', label: this.$t('users.roleOptions.manager')},
        {value: 'leader', label: this.$t('users.roleOptions.leader')},
        {value: 'leader_admin', label: this.$t('users.roleOptions.leader_admin')}
      ]
    };
  },
  methods:  {
    activeIfCoororMan() {
      if(this.newLeader.role === 'manager' || this.newLeader.role === 'coordinator') {
        console.log("remove-disabled")
      } else {
        console.log("stay-disabled")
      }
    },
  }
}
```

when i'm choosing in first select **coordinator** or **manager**, i can see in console: **remove-disable**. But, i would like change `:disable` attribute from second field to `false`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering:

```
ns-dropdown-item(item-id="7")    
  ns-select(:placeholder="$t('users.client')", v-model="client", 
    :options="clients", 
    :disabled="newLeader.role !== 'manager' || newLeader.role !== 'coordinator'")
```

This will add `disabled` property only when role is not manager nor coordinator.

---

But this would be a security issue. Why you're just disabling them? You should not have element rendered at all. Thus, I suggest you to use `v-if` statement so that it will be only rendered when the condition is matched else the element is not present in the DOM.

```
ns-dropdown-item(item-id="7")    
  ns-select(:placeholder="$t('users.client')", v-model="client", 
    :options="clients", 
    v-if="newLeader.role === 'manager' || newLeader.role === 'coordinator'")
```

Comment: It does not work. Error: `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "disabled"` Also, i need this code in one function to call my api service. Thank you!

Comment: From the error, I noticed that you need to initialize the data as `newLeader: {},` instead of `newLeader: null,`

Comment: Thank you, but i'm getting the same error. i need this code out of template, to call my api. Thank you again :)

Comment: It seems to be initialization problem. Try defining like `newLeader: { role: ''}`.